# Can you help me identify a statue?

Tags: sculpture

This is certainly not my expertise. I have no great ideas on how to get started.

I would comment on the the impressive abs and the lack of legs to guess Posedion (Is he presented as a "mer-man" sometimes?)  but the shape of the mustache throws me a little.

An ideal answer would not only answer the question but also speak to the process of statue identification. What questions should I be asking? What should I be looking for?

Thanks so much any help.

[image]

Comment: What is its location?

Comment: This is on a fireplace in a home in the district of Columbia. I assume the home is from the 1960s-1970s

Comment: Then its artistic, not cultural. Could be anything.Look to other elements of the homes architecture, or original owners for clues.

Comment: Classically a statue that hold something up is a "caryatid" -- technically caryatids are female -- image searches for "male caryatid" may turn up something that is similar.  https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=isch&q=male+caryatid

Comment: It's a "Green Man". Take a look on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Man

Comment: @AllInOne The male equivalent of a caryatid is usually referred to as an '_atlas_', an '_atlantid_', or a '_telamon_'.